# Pyspark vectorized UDF with conditional

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to evaluate the following condition to add a column in Spark dataframe.

```
@pandas_udf(returnType=StringType())
def test(email, headers):
    if email is not None:
        return email
    else:
        return = headers.str.get("default")
```

What's the best way to check if email is null? I have tried several options but nothing works.

```
res = df.withColumn("out", test(col("email"), col("headers"))
```

Even if `col("name")` is null the else condition is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be better of using built-in Spark SQL functions than defining a UDF, it will be much more performant.

Something like this works:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("email1@hotmail.com", "header1"),
        ("email2@hotmail.com", "header2"),
        (None, "header3"),
        ("email3@hotmail.com", "header4"),
        (None, "header5"),
    ],
    ["email", "headers"],
)


df.withColumn(
    "out", F.when(F.col("email").isNull(), F.col("headers")).otherwise(F.col("email"))
).show()
+------------------+-------+------------------+                                 
|             email|headers|               out|
+------------------+-------+------------------+
|email1@hotmail.com|header1|email1@hotmail.com|
|email2@hotmail.com|header2|email2@hotmail.com|
|              null|header3|           header3|
|email3@hotmail.com|header4|email3@hotmail.com|
|              null|header5|           header5|
+------------------+-------+------------------+
```

The [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) function gives you the "if" functionality you're looking for.